# Finding Centre or Symmetric Line of a Segmentation Image

Tags: object, line, detection, symmetry

I have an image dataset consisting of segmentation images where the target object is rectangular ship (segmented as white or 1) and hence everything else in the background is black or 0. I have drawn the blue line to depict the longitudinal symmetric line in one of the sample images. I need to know the pixels of the longitudinal symmetric line of each of the images in the dataset by using the same technique. Any help or idea will be of great help.[White is the target object, black is background and blue is the required longitudinal symmetric or center line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XI8P.png)

I tried to use finding the contours of the segmentation image and tried to find the average of the pixels but it did not work.